# Assign Unique Numeric Group IDs to Groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've consistently run into this issue of having to assign a unique ID to each group in a data set. I've used this when zero padding for RNN's, generating graphs, and many other occasions.

This can usually be done by concatenating the values in each `pd.groupby` column. However, it is often the case the number of columns that define a group, their dtype, or the value sizes make concatenation an impractical solution that needlessly uses up memory.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to assign a unique numeric ID to groups in pandas.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You just need `ngroup` data from seeiespi (or `pd.factorize`)

```
df.groupby('C').ngroup()
Out[322]: 
0    0
1    0
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    2
dtype: int64
```

More Option

```
pd.factorize(df.C)[0]
Out[323]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
df.C.astype('category').cat.codes
Out[324]: 
0    0
1    0
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    2
dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 12):

I managed a simple solution that I constantly reference and wanted to share:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,6,3,7,3,2],'B':[4,3,8,2,6,3,9,1,0], 'C':['a','a','c','b','b','b','b','c','c']})

df = df.sort_values('C')

df['gid'] = (df.groupby(['C']).cumcount()==0).astype(int)

df['gid'] = df['gid'].cumsum()

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   A  B  C  gid
0  1  4  a    1
1  2  3  a    1
2  3  8  b    2
3  4  2  b    2
4  6  6  b    2
5  3  3  b    2
6  7  9  c    3
7  3  1  c    3
8  2  0  c    3
```